# How to write correct HERE javascript source in html head? Browser always fails to load resource

Tags: javascript, html, maps, here-api

I just want to create a default website, showing a map like this demo from [HEREMaps](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js). The HTML and JavaScript code is already provided, so I just had to put both together and should work, but it seems like there is a mistake.

Unfortunately, my code fails in every browser, because there is no content behind some links to script resources in the HTML head:

- ../template.css
- ../test-credentials.js
- ../js-examples-rendering-helpers/iframe-height.js

This seems obvious to me, but somehow jsFiddle can read this file without any problem and I am quite sure that HEREMaps doesn't provide wrong code, so I would like to know what is wrong with my code.

For safety reasons, I am not going to write my credentials, so `window.apikey` has to be replaced, if you try it out.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Map at a specified location</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../template.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../test-credentials.js'></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../js-examples-rendering-helpers/iframe-height.js'></script> 
  </head>

  <body id="markers-on-the-map">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='demo.js'> 

    /**
     * Moves the map to display over Berlin
     *
     * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
     */

    function moveMapToBerlin(map){
      map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
      map.setZoom(14);
    }

    /**
     * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
     */

    //Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
    // In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      apikey: window.apikey
    });
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    //Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
    var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
      center: {lat:50, lng:5},
      zoom: 4,
      pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
    });
    // add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

    //Step 3: make the map interactive
    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

    // Create the default UI components
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

    // Now use the map as required...
    window.onload = function () {
      moveMapToBerlin(map);
    }  

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the link you provided. I've set up a working example:

```js
// HEREMaps - Demo API Key. You should change this.
var apikey = 'H6XyiCT0w1t9GgTjqhRXxDMrVj9h78ya3NuxlwM7XUs';

/**
 * Moves the map to display over Berlin
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function moveMapToBerlin(map) {
  map.setCenter({
    lat: 52.5159,
    lng: 13.3777
  });
  map.setZoom(14);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
    center: {
      lat: 50,
      lng: 5
    },
    zoom: 4,
    pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
  });
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
window.onload = function() {
  moveMapToBerlin(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 95%;
  height: 450px;
  background: grey;
}

#panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- Map Container -->
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping so fast! Do you know, why the code published by HERE, contains so many unknown links to skript sources? And why do you describe a panel in your css, although it is not defined in the html?